# How to list the objects that aren't as fk in other tables

Tags: python, django

I have a table `Users`, and an user can be in a `Student` table or `Teacher` table.

How can I list only the users that aren't in none of the 2 tables ?

The tables name are in portuguese, but they correspond to User, Teacher and Student respectively.

```
qs = models.Users.objects.all('')
```

---

```
class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    Nome = models.CharField('Nome Completo', max_length=100)
    User = models.CharField('Usuario',max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email',unique=True)
    Data_Associacao = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Ativo',default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["Nome", "User"]
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nome
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.User

class Professor(models.Model):
    Matricula = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8)
    Usuario = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Data_Nascimento = models.DateField('Data de Nascimento')
    Endereco = models.TextField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Usuario.Nome


class Aluno(models.Model):
Matricula = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8)
Usuario = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
Data_Nascimento = models.DateField('Data de Nascimento')
Endereco = models.TextField(max_length=200)
Turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Usuario.Nome

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        super(Aluno, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValidationError:
        raise ValidationError("Não há vagas nesta turma !")
```

Comment: Add code related to User, Student and Teacher model

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
professor = Professor.objects.values_list('Usuario_id', flat=True).all()
aluno = Aluno.objects.values_list('Usuario_id', flat=True).all()

users = list(set(professor + aluno))
user_list = Usuario.objects.exclude(pk__in=users)
```

So `user_list` var has all users that are not in another two tables

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for what I was doing, I don't know whether You ever heard of Django autocomplete light, I'm using this to make an auto complete with the users that are not as teachers or students yet, I'm getting the error. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'

Comment: NeErAj, I did some alteration in my code and it worked, I changed users = list(set(professor + aluno)), to users = chain(professor, aluno), and it worked great, edit your post so other people can see your very helpfull answer, thanks friend and if possible explain a bit more your code I'm insterested in knowing what You did there.